# Application wants access to keyring default in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot

At every boot of ubunutu 13.10 I get the message:

```
An application wants to access keyring default, but it is locked.
```

What is it? Why am I getting this? Please guide a newbie. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set Ubuntu to automatically login at startup or are you using a wireless connection to the network?

If yes,

1. click the Network Managers icon on the Panel
2. Edit Connections
3. Wireless Tab
4. Tick **Automatically Connect** and **Available for all Users**.

Comment: I am using a wired connection. The network is set to connect to wireless connection when available automatically.